# create one time reference for various sample rates per file

Tags: c#

My program reads in multiple files that contain time/value pairs sampled at different rates. I'm trying to use the file with the highest sample rate as the time scale for all sampled rates and output one master file with the unique time values from the highest sample rate file.

Each file contains time/values pairs like:

1,58

1.5,90

2,154

2.5,34

Here is my code so far:

```
public void ReadAndWrite(string[] fileNames)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    List<StreamReader> readers = fileNames.Select(f => new StreamReader(f)).ToList();

    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tbxOutputFile.Text))
        {
            string line = null;

            // For each measurement in max measurements
            for (int measNum = 0; measNum < numOfRows; measNum++)
            {                        
                // For each file's reader
                for (int i = 0; i < readers.Count; i++)
                {
                    // If line contains something, then add it to line
                    if ((line = readers[i].ReadLine()) != null)
                    {                           
                        // Process line and then write it to file
                        line = ProcessLine(line);
                        writer.Write(line);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writer.Write("");
                    }
                    // If it's not the last column, add delimiter
                    if (i < readers.Count - 1)
                        writer.Write(",");
                }
                writer.WriteLine();

                // Update labels
                int val = ((measNum + 1) * 100) / numOfRows;
                string newText = Convert.ToString("Progress: " + val + "% " + "     " + "Measurement #: " + (measNum + 1)
                    + " out of " + numOfRows); // running on worker thread
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    // runs on UI thread
                    lblStatus.Text = newText;                            
                    progressBar1.Value = val;
                });
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (var reader in readers)
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("File successfully created! " + '\n' + "Elapsed time: " + 
        (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000) + " seconds", "Processing Complete");            
}
```

I came up with the pseudo code below (currentTime is the time from each file and uniqueTime is from an array that reads in each time from the highest sampled file):

```
// if time value from individual file is same as uniqueTime
if currentTime == uniqueTime
{
    valueToWrite = curr_value // write the current value
}
else // currentTime is not same as uniqueTime
{
    valueToWrite = prev_value // write the previous value
}
timeToWrite = uniqueTime // always write the uniqueTime
```

What is the best way to execute this pseudo code to make a unique time reference for all the various sample rates? Sorry if my question is confusing, I can elaborate more if need be.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear about this, you do not want the values at the specific time they occurred, but you  want to display one value for each source at each timepoint that the highest sampled source has?
That should be pretty straightforward. In pseudocode:

```cs
foreach (ValuePair val in highSampleRateValues) {
    var aggregatedTimePointData;
    aggregatedTimePointData.Add(val.Time, val.Value);
    foreach (ValuePair val2 in lowSampleRateValues) {
        var value = DetermineLatestEntryBackwardFrom(val.Time);
        aggregatedTimePointData.Add(value);
    }
}
```

This way, the sample rate of the higher density sampled signal serves as a clock, but you will have inaccuracies since the values from the other sources are only close, but not exactly on the timepoint of their recording. If you want those inaccuracies reduced, choose a higher sample rate and do the same thing. You can get as close to the actual timepoints as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I think your pseudo code resembles what I want to do, but I'm still trying to implement this in actual code. I'll let you know if I figure it out, or if someone else posts a code snippet that works.

Comment: Well, how well did you abstract things? I won't go about and design a whole model, but if you show me what you have so far, I might be able and willing to help with the actual implementation (or somebody else might).

Comment: Oh, I probably should be more precise here: To actually help, it would be really nice if you abstracted everything so far that the problem is isolated, by which I essentially want to say, reading those values from the file should not be in the sample you provided, and neither should UI-related stuff. Keep it simple and focused. Maybe designing an abstraction will already enable you to resolve your problem.